# NTP syncs with ntp.ubuntu.com but not with the pool options

Tags: sync, time, ntp

I am trying to configure my ntp server to synchronize with ntp servers available online.

Below is my /etc/inet/ntp.conf and my ntpq -p output

```
# ident "@(#)ntp.server 1.6     00/07/17 SMI"
#
# /etc/inet/ntp.server
#
# An example file that could be copied over to /etc/inet/ntp.conf and
# edited; it provides a configuration template for a server that
# listens to an external hardware clock, synchronizes the local clock,
# and announces itself on the NTP multicast net.
#

# This is the external clock device.  The following devices are
# recognized by xntpd 3-5.93e:
#
# XType Device    RefID          Description
# -------------------------------------------------------
#  1    local     LCL            Undisciplined Local Clock
#  2    trak      GPS            TRAK 8820 GPS Receiver
#  3    pst       WWV            PSTI/Traconex WWV/WWVH Receiver
#  4    wwvb      WWVB           Spectracom WWVB Receiver
#  5    true      TRUE           TrueTime GPS/GOES Receivers
#  6    irig      IRIG           IRIG Audio Decoder
#  7    chu       CHU            Scratchbuilt CHU Receiver
#  8    parse     ----           Generic Reference Clock Driver
#  9    mx4200    GPS            Magnavox MX4200 GPS Receiver
# 10    as2201    GPS            Austron 2201A GPS Receiver
# 11    arbiter   GPS            Arbiter 1088A/B GPS Receiver
# 12    tpro      IRIG           KSI/Odetics TPRO/S IRIG Interface
# 13    leitch    ATOM           Leitch CSD 5300 Master Clock Controller
# 15    *         *              TrueTime GPS/TM-TMD Receiver
# 17    datum     DATM           Datum Precision Time System
# 18    acts      ACTS           NIST Automated Computer Time Service
# 19    heath     WWV            Heath WWV/WWVH Receiver
# 20    nmea      GPS            Generic NMEA GPS Receiver
# 22    atom      PPS            PPS Clock Discipline
# 23    ptb       TPTB           PTB Automated Computer Time Service
# 24    usno      USNO           USNO Modem Time Service
# 25    *         *              TrueTime generic receivers
# 26    hpgps     GPS            Hewlett Packard 58503A GPS Receiver
# 27    arc       MSFa           Arcron MSF Receiver
#
# * All TrueTime receivers are now supported by one driver, type 5.
#   Types 15 and 25 will be retained only for a limited time and may
#   be reassigned in future.
#
# Some of the devices benefit from "fudge" factors.  See the xntpd
# documentation.

# Either a peer or server.  Replace "XType" with a value from the
# table above.
####server 127.127.1.0 prefer ########################for local
####fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 2 ###### FOR LOCAL @@@@$$$$


#fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 1
# STARTING FOR SYNC OYUTSIDE ####################
server 0.pool.ntp.org
server 1.pool.ntp.org
server 2.pool.ntp.org
server pool.ntp.org
server ntp.ubuntu.com
## END FOR SYC OYUT SIDE ###########################
#broadcast 224.0.1.1 ttl 4

#enable auth monitor
driftfile /var/ntp/ntp.drift
#statsdir /var/ntp/ntpstats/
#filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
#filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
#filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

#keys /etc/inet/ntp.keys
#trustedkey 0
#requestkey 0
#controlkey 0
```

```
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset    disp
==============================================================================
 ns.dsl.net.pk   0.0.0.0         16 -    - 1024    0     0.00    0.000 16000.0
 khi77.pie.net.p 0.0.0.0         16 -    - 1024    0     0.00    0.000 16000.0
*golem.canonical ntp0.rrze.uni-e  2 u   34   64  377   245.94   -3.132    7.90
```

This server is running solaris 9. I can not figure out why it would synchronize with one but not the others. I have checked with the network guys and the port 123 is open for this particular server. 
Using ntpdate -u shows that the server is sending and receiving packets.
Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated

Edit: Hashed "fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 1" and removed prefer from the servers
Adding dmesg output after making edits

```
May 27 12:47:47 smtp-01 ntpdate[29499]: [ID 558275 daemon.notice] adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset -0.046348 sec
May 27 12:47:49 smtp-01 xntpd[29516]: [ID 702911 daemon.notice] xntpd 3-5.93e Mon Sep 20 15:47:11 PDT 1999 (1)
May 27 12:47:49 smtp-01 xntpd[29516]: [ID 301315 daemon.notice] tickadj = 5, tick = 10000, tvu_maxslew = 495, est. hz = 100
May 27 12:47:49 smtp-01 xntpd[29516]: [ID 798731 daemon.notice] using kernel phase-lock loop 0041
```

New ntpq -p output

```
bash-2.05# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset    disp
==============================================================================
 khi77.pie.net.p 0.0.0.0         16 -    -   64    0     0.00    0.000 16000.0
*europium.canoni ntp0.rrze.uni-e  2 u   31   64  377   155.29   -0.299    1.65
```

Comment: Can you comment out the `fudge` line and remove the `prefer` options. the fact that you are prefering 3 servers (two of which are pooled) gives me the idea that you do not understand why you have prefer in the config. after you make those changes and restart can you include the log output for ntpd?

Comment: I have attached the dmesg output after making changes Also I seem to have lost one server

Comment: I just saw that you are using xntp. That is 15 years old, i am not sure I can be much help. Can you run a version from this millennium?